# In terms of Red Sox, why there were 4 games against Rays while 3 games against Yankees?

Tags: baseball, mlb

This is the [schedule](https://www.google.com/search?q=red%20sox%20schedule%20in%20september%202020&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=red%20sox%20schedule%20in%20september%202020&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.9636j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=t;/m/01d5z;4;/m/09p14;mt;fp;1;;) for Red Sox in September in 2020.

[image]

Why there were 4 games against Rays while just 3 games against the Yankees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: they played the Yankees 7 times in July and August, while they played the Rays 6 times in July and August.  Since the MLB schedule in 2020 was to play 10 games against each of the 4 same-division teams (for 40 games) plus 20 games against teams in the other division, that left 4 more games against the Rays, and 3 more against the Yankees to play in September.

See [MLB's announcement on the 2020 schedule for more details](https://www.mlb.com/news/2020-major-league-baseball-schedule-released), or [Baseball-Reference's schedule and score list](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2020-schedule-scores.shtml) for the breakdown of their results.

Baseball teams typically play between two and four game sets against other teams; how many depends on the specific details of the schedule.  Typically the Fri-Sun days are always against one team, and Tue-Weds are always against one team, and then Mon and/or Thurs go with one or the other of those sets (so they might play Tues-Thurs then Fri-Sun, or Mon-Weds then Thurs-Sun, or Mon-Thurs then Fri-Sun, or Tue-Weds then Fri-Sun, or something similar).  The exact details just depends on how the other team's schedule matches theirs.